# Parse text from website without class and id

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

Ho i can parse site, if on it missing class and id. xpath dont work too, or i do something wrong.
I want get info about game - system requiments, data and other information. How i can do this so that output looks like in the desription?
[image]

My full code - https://github.com/FreedomEssence/Torrent-Ighruha_Parser/blob/master/__init__.py

Comment: please post the link to the site you want to scrape. We're not magicians

Comment: @Chase, you can find it in his code on github

Comment: Sorry)
https://torrent-igruha.org/newgames/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the css selector `#dle-content > div:nth-child(3)` to locate this element.

```py
divtext = soup.select('#dle-content > div:nth-child(3)')[0].text
```

Output-

```py
'\nДата обновления: 2019Жанр: Action, Tank, 3D, Online-onlyРазработчик: Wargaming.netИздательство в России: Wargaming.netТип издания: ЛицензияЯзык интерфейса: РусскийЯзык озвучки: РусскийТаблетка: Не требуетсяСистемные требования:Операционная система:  XP / Vista / 7 / 8 / 10Процессор: Pentium 4 2,4 GHzОперативная память: 4 ГбВидеокарта: 512 Mb - 1024 Mb / nVIDIA / ATI Radeon®Звуковая карта: Звуковое устройство DirectX® 9.0сСвободное место на жестком диске: 16 Гб\n \n\n   \n\n\n'
```

Comment: And one more question) How i can sort this... text into normal view?

Comment: @FreedomEssence you can use regex to parse the resulting text and extract your required information. I'd do that myself in my answer but I neither understand the language nor do I know which exact pieces you want to extract.